# XPath expression to set empty index

Tags: php, xpath

I have this sort of HTML, (simplifying here).

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Name 1</div>
        <div class="phone">phone 1</div>
    </li
    <li>
        <div class="name">Name 2</div>
        // no div available here
    </li
    <li>
        <div class="name">Name 3</div>
        <div class="phone">phone 3</div>
    </li
</ul>
```

xPaths look like this,

```
$names = $crawler->filterXPath('//ul//li//div[@class="name"]')->extract('_text');
$phones = $crawler->filterXPath('//ul//li//div[@class="phone"]')->extract('_text');
```

It return these arrays,

```
$names = array(  
        0    =>    Name 1  
        1    =>    Name 2  
        2    =>    Name 3  

)

$phones = array(  
        0    =>    Phone 1  
        1    =>    Phone 3  

)
```

Now I want, if xpath doesn't find any div there at index 1, it should be replace by null or empty.

So the indexes of both these arrays should be same as,

```
$phones = array(  
        0    =>    Phone 1  
        1    =>    null or empty
        2    =>    Phone 3  

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want associate phones and names ...
This answer not exactly what you want but, you can union that two queries

```
//ul//li//div[@class="name"] | //ul//li//div[@class="phone"]
```

and got nodes in order like that

```
<div class="name">Name 1</div>
<div class="phone">phone 1</div>
<div class="name">Name 2</div>
<div class="name">Name 3</div>
<div class="phone">phone 3</div>
```

and next just check the order in your code.

Comment: I appreciate you efforts, But this is not what I want. thanks for your time man.